# Check if element is in a tree

Tags: lisp

I need to write a function in Lisp that checks if an element N is in a tree TREE.

```
(defun TREE-CONTAINS (N TREE)
    (cond ((equal TREE nil) nil)
        ((listp (CAR TREE)) (or (TREE-CONTAINS(N (CAR TREE))) 
                                (TREE-CONTAINS(N (CDR TREE)))))
        (t (cond ((equal N (CAR TREE)) t)
                  (t TREE-CONTAINS(N (CDR TREE)))))
    )
)
```

For example, `(TREE-CONTAINS (1 ((1  2 3) 4 5)))` will return true. But I keep getting an error that says "Undefined function N called with arguments `((2 3))`" when I test my code with this example: `(TREE-CONTAINS 2 '(1 2 3))`. Of course N is supposed to be 1 here but I don't know why it thinks N is a function. Any idea?

Comment: SO has code formatting with the `{}` and code within text you can enclose in backticks eg. `` `code` `` to get that formatted as well. When you put parentheses around a name you call it as a function. `(+ 1 2)` calls `+`. What do you think `(N (CDR TREE))` would do but try to call `N`?

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. But when I remove the parenthesis around CDR TREE I get unbound CDR.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `(cdr tree)` is correct, but it wasn't supposed to be the argument to `n`. You are probably familiar with algol languages so what you did is like `n(cdr(tree))` in Java.. but while `cdr` is a function `n` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the call to `tree-contains`, or any lisp function, you should not include parentheses around the arguments. It's `(function-name arg1 arg2)`, not `(function-name (arg1 arg2))`.

So for a start, remove the parentheses around the arguments to the call `(tree-contains(n (car tree)))` like so: `(tree-contains n (car tree))`. Similarly for the next call to `tree-contains` in that `or` clause. Besides, the last condition: `(t TREE-CONTAINS(N (CDR TREE)))` should be called like this: `(t (tree-contains n (cdr tree)))`.